# Is it possible to use an old phone as a display for a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-zero-w, display

I am trying to turn an old phone into a portable Raspberry Pi. I want to wire a Raspberry Pi Zero W into it's display and battery. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: yes, it is possible ... find a datasheet for the display that includes the connector pinout, a description of each pin and a command set ... design and build the necessary interface ... write a program to display images

Answer (score 0):

If your old phone is an android

**Step 1.** Turn on the wifi hot spot on your Android phone.

**Step 2.** Connect the raspberry pi to the phone's wifi network.

**Step 3.** Set up the VNC as if you were connected to a regular router.

The phone and the pi are on the same wifi network so can communicate without even having any internet access.
Credit [googleverse](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=204028)

If you have an apple iphone here's a slightly more complicated process
Credit [Being Engineers](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Use-Ios-Devices-As-a-Monitor-of-Raspberry-P/)

As for wiring it into your phone battery it may be easier to get a [LiPo Battery HAT](https://thepihut.com/products/lipo-battery-hat-for-raspberry-pi)  Although I'll admit i'm not very knowledgeable about this aspect, and I cannot just comment this (not enough reputation).

Comment: The phone is dead but the screen still works, so VNC wouldn't work.